# elasticsearch: I cannot retrieve hit.from of a json document

Tags: python, json, elasticsearch

I was trying to print the result of a query and I figured out that I cannot retrieve `hit.from` of a `json` document.
It tells me `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.
`from` is a field of the `json` doc which represents an email.

I post here the code of the query:

```
client = Elasticsearch()

query_string = raw_input("Enter your query string: ")
print(query_string)

s = Search(using=client, index="enron_test")
    .query("match", message_body=query_string)

response = s.execute()
```

and here the code to print the results:

```
for hit in response:
    print(hit.from)
    print(hit.to)
    print(hit.message_body)
    print(line + "\n")
```

the strange thing is that `from` is highlighted in grey.

Here is the `json` doc:

```
 {
            "_index": "enron_test",
            "_type": "enron_type",
            "_id": "AVzjqJ_-Jz9fMnhSpbdm",
            "_score": 1.7868237,
            "_source": {
               "message_body": "'Arry (calxa@aol.com), Lime Ex-splurt Extraordinaire...
               "content-transfer-encoding": "7bit",
               "file_name": "2.",
               "sub_holder": "",
               "subject": "Re: History of  Lime and Cement",
               "x-cc": "strawbale@crest.org",
               "from": "rob_tom@freenet.carleton.ca",
               "x-folder": "\\Phillip_Allen_Dec2000\\Notes Folders\\Straw",
               "content_size_in_bytes": 1811,
               "to": "calxa@aol.com",
               "x-origin": "Allen-P",
               "mime-version": "1.0",
               "x-bcc": "",
               "x-filename": "pallen.nsf",
               "date": "Thu, 17 Feb 2000 07:37:00 -0800 (PST)",
               "x-to": "CALXA@aol.com",
               "loaded_on": "2017-06-26",
               "cc": "strawbale@crest.org",
               "bcc": "strawbale@crest.org",
               "x-from": "rob_tom@freenet.carleton.ca (Robert W. Tom)",
               "message-id": "<22208447.1075855692838.JavaMail.evans@thyme>",
               "content-type": "text/plain; charset=us-ascii"
            }
         },
```

Comment: Can we see the json data ?

Comment: I posted an example of `json` doc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elasticsearch results contain a bunch of other fields giving you more information about the document as well as the content itself.

`{
    "took": 1,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards":{
        "total" : 1,
        "successful" : 1,
        "failed" : 0
    },
    "hits":{
        "total" : 1,
        "max_score": 1.3862944,
        "hits" : [
            {
                "_index" : "twitter",
                "_type" : "tweet",
                "_id" : "0",
                "_score": 1.3862944,
                "_source" : {
                    "user" : "kimchy",
                    "message": "trying out Elasticsearch",
                    "date" : "2009-11-15T14:12:12",
                    "likes" : 0
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}`

So in order to get the `from` field out of your actual document you'll need to do:

`for hit in response['hits']['hits']:
        print(hit['_source']['from'])`

Comment: It doesn't work. It tells me `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: It works! Even if I cannot understand why my original code worked for `hit.to`  and `hit.message_body` and not for `hit.from`. Thank you man, I appreciate that!